# Linear Algebra transformation eigenvector question

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was just wondering if there is a $2\times2$- rotation matrix that does not have a strictly complex eigenvalue like $0+xi$ where $x$ does not equal $0$.

Also is there a real $3\times3$-matrix whose eigenvalues are strictly complex?

Comment: sorry i meant to say 2 x 2 rotation matrix

Comment: nvm I found the answer if I have theta=0 i don't get any complex eigenvalues

Comment: $\theta = \pi$ also works. In fact, these are the only two that work.

Answer (score 0):

If a 3x3 matrix has only real entries, then the characteristic polynomial is a real polynomial of degree 3. It's easy to prove that a real polynomial can have complex roots only as complex conjugates. So a 3x3 matrix must have a real root.

Consider the matrix:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1/\sqrt{5} & -2/\sqrt{5}\\
2/\sqrt{5} & 1/\sqrt{5}
\end{pmatrix}$

Then the eigenvalues of $A$ aren't strictly complex.